# Combining R language based algorithm to html web page for creating a web application

Tags: r, web

I am creating a web application. I have made a algorithm in R language and a front end in html/jQuery. How can i combine the algorithm to the front end so that when the user enters data in the html page he gets an output run on the algorithm written in R, on the html page as output.

Comment: Maybe the libraries `Rook` and `shiny` are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using [RApache,](http://rapache.net/) you can connect between javascript and R. It allows you to do the server side scripting in R. 
To make this work, set up an R script on your server, make sure the directives in Apache are set ok - something like this will work

```
<Directory /var/www/brew/pathtoyourscript>
    SetHandler r-script
    RHandler brew::brew
</Directory>
```

And next call the script as you would do with php when you press a button e.g. It will get the parameters which you pass on to the script so that you can use it in R.